# titleView image appears and disappears immediately

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to add my image on UINavigationItem using this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navItemTop.titleView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill

        self.navItemTop.titleView? = ViewController4.navigationImage! //my image, its correct for sure

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    }
```

When i go to another UIViewController and then go back, image appears and disappears a second later. I've tried to put this piece of code in viewWillAppear() method, but result is the same.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Set image in the `viewWillAppear:` method

Comment: You are probably losing the correct reference of navigationImage in ViewController4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image in the `viewWillAppear:` method.

**Reason:** When you are push or Present Sometime there is possibility that we can set another image or clear color to Nav. Bar that's why `viewDidLoad:` method not called on back you lost your old settings of nav. Bar.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add it inside UIImageView:-**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "yourimage.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:image)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```